# Blender BGE slow motion problem

Tags: python, game-engine

first sorry for my bad english.
logic.setTimeScale(0.1) is only slowing the gravity and Animations down, 
but not the Actuators, so i can press "w" and im fast as normal.
I tested it with logic bricks and python - same result, not slowing down.
I want a slow motion for the hole game.

How can i fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you are using the "loc" tab on the actuator (red). You should use the Linear Velocity tab instead (purple).

[image]

The loc section works by teleporting the object a certain distance per frame whereas the Linear Velocity tab actually takes time into account.